# Как сделать видимые значки редактирования WP?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Говорят надо Selective Refresh in the Customizer. Но я вообще ничего не понял из документации и как это мне может помочь. Если кто шарит может один пример создания секции в customizer которая будет подсвечиваться карандашом.

Answer (score 5):

Вот пример:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_customizer' );
function theme_customizer() {
    $customize->add_setting(
        'phone',
        array(
            'transport'         => 'postMessage',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_attr',
        )
    );
    $customize->add_control(
        'phone',
        array(
            'section' => 'title_tagline',
            'label'   => __( 'Phone', 'domain' ),
            'type'    => 'text'
        )
    );
    if ( isset( $customize->selective_refresh ) ) {
        $customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'phone', array(
            'selector'        => '.header__phone',
            'render_callback' => 'customizer_phone_callback',
        ) );
    }
}

function customizer_phone_callback() {
    echo get_theme_mod('phone');
}
```

Здесь три основные вещи:

1. `phone` - это название опции, при клике на кардашь будет выделяться это поле
2. `selector` - css-селектор, по которому в ДОМе можно найти данный
   блок, после этого появится карандаш)
3. `render_callback` - функция, которая будет выводить результат. При изменении поля в селектор выводится результат функции-колбека)

Comment: Хороший ответ, только слова blogname в коде я не вижу

Comment: спасибо, поправил)